# .htaccess allow access to more than one file PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a three files that I would like to allow access to, (home.php, contact.php, login.php). I also have a folder containing assets (assets) that I would like to deny direct access to.

This is my code but its denying access to every file/folder.

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

<Files "home.php|contact.php|login.php">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

I've looked on SO, but no one covered this topic, so this aint a duplicate.

THANKS

Comment: Create `.htaccess` file with `Deny From All` line and put that file directory in `assets` folder.

Comment: thanks @MA but if I do that, then my index.php file can't access the css and js from the assets folder to render the page style

Comment: Then you can use `Files` directive to allow specific file types i.e.  css and js like you did for php files.

Comment: hmm could you please show me in an example @MA

Comment: Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example shows how you can allow only few file types and deny other requests. Add this to your `assets` folder.

```
Order Allow,Deny

<FilesMatch "\.(html|css|js)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow From All
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks will I be able to access any of the files in the assets folder through my index.php file, when no one can access it directly?

Comment: All public files including css and js are downloaded by browser so if you block access to them then nobody will be able to access them and your site won't work as expected.

Comment: Cool but how do I deny direct access and allow access to the files in the assets folder only from the index.php file. I realised that the code above denies access to the file extensions but I will need to access it from the index.php file

Comment: These files aren't required by index.php but the client (browser) so if you want to block these files then they won't see anything and your site won't work properly.

Comment: Thanks but if I have an important php file that I don't want anyone to access, except my index.php file, how do I do that

Comment: If you include php file then it's fine because it will be included using filesystem. Using `<FilesMatch "\.(html|css|js)$">` will only allow html,css, and js files so nobody will be able to access php files and your script won't have issues including any php files.